# Feed YouTube in listbox Error

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have tried used this code for insert feeds in listbox but with youtube feeds it not work. Sorry but I do not know much about xml

```
XmlDocument RSSXml = new XmlDocument();
RSSXml.Load("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/google/uploads");

XmlNodeList RSSNodeList = RSSXml.SelectNodes("feed");
XmlNode RSSDesc = RSSXml.SelectSingleNode("feed");

 foreach (XmlNode RSSNode in RSSNodeList)
 {
     XmlNode RSSSubNode;
     RSSSubNode = RSSNode.SelectSingleNode("title");
     string title = RSSSubNode != null ? RSSSubNode.InnerText : "";
     RSSSubNode = RSSNode.SelectSingleNode("link");
     string link = RSSSubNode != null ? RSSSubNode.InnerText : "";
     listBox1.Items.Add(title);                   
}
```

instead, this works

```
//Fetch the subscribed RSS Feed
XmlDocument RSSXml = new XmlDocument();
RSSXml.Load("mywebsite/feed/");

XmlNodeList RSSNodeList = RSSXml.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item");
XmlNode RSSDesc = RSSXml.SelectSingleNode("rss/channel/title");

foreach (XmlNode RSSNode in RSSNodeList)
{
    XmlNode RSSSubNode;
    RSSSubNode = RSSNode.SelectSingleNode("title");
    string title = RSSSubNode != null ? RSSSubNode.InnerText : "";
    RSSSubNode = RSSNode.SelectSingleNode("link");
    string link = RSSSubNode != null ? RSSSubNode.InnerText : "";                                       
    listBox1.Items.Add(title);
    listBox2.Items.Add(link); 
}
```

Thanks for your answers

Comment: So you have code that works. What is your question?

Comment: the code works for my website not for youtube feeds!

Comment: Purely FYI there is also a SyndicationFeed class. It handles Atom and RSS for most common feeds (except facebook) nicely, without having to fiddle with the namespaces and xmlNode querying. It does it all in code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces do mather in selecting nodes in an xml document. You have to add a namespacemanger and explicitly indicate which element you want. Also selecting attributes (for the link) is different than just innertext of an element.

```
     XmlDocument RSSXml = new XmlDocument(); 
     RSSXml.Load("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/google/uploads");  

    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(RSSXml.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("tns", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

    XmlNodeList RSSNodeList = RSSXml.SelectNodes("//tns:entry", nsmgr); 
    XmlNode RSSDesc = RSSXml.SelectSingleNode("tns:feed",nsmgr);   

    foreach (XmlNode RSSNode in RSSNodeList)  {      
        XmlNode RSSSubNode;      
        RSSSubNode = RSSNode.SelectSingleNode("tns:title", nsmgr);      
        string title = RSSSubNode != null ? RSSSubNode.InnerText : "";      
        RSSSubNode = RSSNode.SelectSingleNode("tns:link/@href",nsmgr);      
        string link = RSSSubNode != null ? RSSSubNode.InnerText : "";      

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",title, link);
    }
```

See [SelectNodes with a namespacemanager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9.aspx)